# Using Eval() and assert-string() function in CLIPS

Tags: clips

I embed the CLIPS in C++ program.

Now I am doing this:

`Eval("(assert-string "(inputdata (value 1))")", &result)`

I find that the two semicolons will cause problem. `"(assert-string "` seem to be recognized as a entity.
So how can I fix this problem.

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape your quotes:

```
Eval("(assert-string \"(inputdata (value 1))\")", &result)
```